# Token incompatible with solidity parser as part of pragrma directive

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm using Remix IDE to compile a simple contract function. I'm fairly new to Solidity and have tried using different combinations of the compiler version and that of the parser solidity command. The problem still persists.

```
pragma solidity ˆ0.4.0;
uint storedData;
function set(uint x) public {
    storedData = x;
}
function get() contsant public returns (uint) {
    return storedData;
}
funtion increment (uint n) public {
    storedData = storedData + n;
}
funtion decrement (uint n) public {
    storedData = storedData - n;
}
```

None of the older answers to similar questions has solved my issue.
The error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code has a couple of issues:

- The character before `0.4.0` should be a `^` (Circumflex Accent U+005E), and not `ˆ` (Modifier Letter Circumflex Accent U+02C6).
- The functions should be inside a `contract NN {}`, solc 0.4 doesn't allow standalone functions.
- There are a few types `funtion`, `contsant`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Test {

    uint storedData;

    function set(uint x) public {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() constant public returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
    }

    function increment (uint n) public {
        storedData = storedData + n;
    }

    function decrement (uint n) public {
        storedData = storedData - n;
    }
}
```